# Round numbers in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to round numbers in a Word document, as I couldn't find a built-in way, here is my approach, it rounds all numbers in selection.

As I use VBA mainly in Excel I'm not sure whether I've done it the best way possible:

```
Sub RoundNumbers()
    Dim OrigRng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Dim FindPattern As String
    Dim FoundVal As String

    Set OrigRng = Selection.Range
    Set WorkRng = Selection.Range
    FindPattern = "([0-9]){1,}.[0-9]{1,}"

    Do
        With WorkRng
            .SetRange OrigRng.Start, OrigRng.End ' using "set WorkRng = OrigRng" would cause them to point to the same object (OrigRng is also changed when WorkRng is changed)
            If .Find.Execute(findtext:=FindPattern, Forward:=True, _
                    MatchWildcards:=True) Then
                .Expand wdWord ' I couldn't find a reliable way for greedy matching with Word regex, so I expand found range to word
                .Text = round(CDbl(.Text) + 0.000001) ' VBA's round() perform bankers' rounding, adding a small number is a quick fix which works for my data
            End If
        End With
    Loop While WorkRng.Find.Found
End Sub
```

Input example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 15.12. Duis vestibulum gravida elit 3.1415, ac pretium neque suscipit ut. Pellentesque eu ipsum quam. 

| 94.3 | 1.5  | 39   | 6.5  |
| 62.4 | 56.6 | 96.4 | 46.4 |
| 92   | 1.2  | 62.1 | 77.6 |
| 55.4 | 83.3 | 44.3 | 49.5 |
| 13.9 | 8.5  | 95.2 | 14.4 |
| 62.5 | 37.4 | 24   | 23.4 |
| 71.9 | 81.6 | 10.3 | 21.6 |

Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse nec elementum massa. Donec sit amet volutpat ligula.
```

Comment: Could you add some mock-data?

Comment: @TinMan: added sample input

Comment: Nice work!  I read the article but that recommended adding `+0.000001` but did not think that it applied to whole numbers.

Comment: @TinMan: adding `0.000001` is needed to avoid performing bankers' rounding